# What is the name of the Owner Field in csv for Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api

We are trying to  Upsert records for account using Bulk API.The CSV file contains a field named "OWNER". While performing the operation we get the error as

> Field name not found:"Owner"

Comment: Try ownerid instead of owner

Comment: If I do so,I am getting the following error in result.          INVALID_FIELD:Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for User:--

Comment: Got it Thanks.But why is that we are using "OwnerID" while the API name of the Account Owner is "Owner"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API name of the field you are looking for is **OwnerId**. You need to populate it with a User Id.

Comment: If I do so,I am getting the following error in result. INVALID_FIELD:Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for User:-- –

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going wrong. Your csv should have a column with header OwnerId where you have to put an 15 or 18-digit User Id.

Comment: Got it Thanks.But why is that we are using "OwnerID" while the API name of the Account Owner is "Owner"?

Comment: It's not: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm

Comment: But we do have a  field named "Account Owner" with API name as "Owner" right?why should we use ownerId then?and why ownerID not available in fields section of Accounts?

Comment: No, the API name of the field is OwnerId. I know it's a bit confusing, since in the UI of Setup it shows up as Owner. Same goes for RecordType for example, the API name is RecordTypeId.